# How to run get_or_create() method with dictionary {'field_name': field_value, ...}?

Tags: django, django-models

I need some kind of universal solution, (btw. eval(), exec() and ideas like this are not permitted). So..

I have some dictionary of fields:
dict = {'field_name_1': field_value_1, 'field_name_2': field_name_2, ...} and I would like to run: 
`Class.objects.get_or_create(dict)`.

Is it possible? How to do this correctly?

Comment: `Class.objects.get_or_create(**dict)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `field_name_1`, `field_name_2`, etc. are the model's attribute names:

```
Model.objects.get_or_create(**dict)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with update_or_create, should it?
eg: `Model.objects.update_or_create(**dict, defaults={'id': id})`

Comment: It should be - Model.objects.update_or_create(field_name_1=1, defaults=dict), here kwargs are used to fetch the existing record.